# How do I convert a DateTime with the GMT offset to UTC in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, utc

I receive this DateTime from a payload: 2016-09-18T11:00:00.000-04:00.

I want to convert it to UTC. I know I just need to take the offset and modify the hours based on that, but I can't find the syntax to do this using the input in the format it is given to me.

Expected Result: 2016-09-18T15:00:00.000

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your problem?

Comment: Where is your DateTime class coming from? JodaTime? Can you show the code you've already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is in ISO format, so with Java 8+ it's fairly simple:

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-09-18T11:00:00.000-04:00");
OffsetDateTime utc = dateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC); //2016-09-18T15:00Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using SimpleDateFormat:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat iso_8601_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");

    Date date = iso_8601_format.parse("2016-09-18T11:00:00.000-04:00");

    iso_8601_format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    System.out.println(iso_8601_format.format(date));
}
```

This results in the following output: 
2016-09-18T15:00:00.000Z

The literal 'Z' at the end is indicative of "Z"ero offset, or UTC.  You could manually strip that off if you need to, but if you are using ISO 8601 as your format of choice, either is valid.